# css3 - aligning objects in a responsive grid

Tags: css, css-float

everyone !
I'm facing some challenge here. Basically, I've this scenario...

- a side bar with fixed width
- containers with fixed width and height where the numbers of the containers in a row must be according with the available width on the screen
- another div upon the containers where the **width always must match the width of the containers** in a single grow (and this is the challenge itself) - see the picture and notice the grey dots.
- When I resize the screen, the containers must wrap when the space is not enough

[image: Expected Scenario]

I made many attempts to make the green box get aligned with the blue containers. Also I'm not sure if this is the best approach to do the things. I created the #group div expecting to make the topper aligns automatically. Also the containers had margins bottom and right to looks like a grid, so I'm not sure if it's the best way to perform this - I'm trying to say: we can change anything, except: the master div must exists, side bar must exists and things with fixed width must stay as fixed width.

Here is the code, but you can see it running at [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/hUxfWthQGpUq4zpyrx9F)

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
<style>
    body,
    html {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: black;
        margin: 0;
    }

    #app {
        width: 100%;
    }

    #sideBar {
        background-color:red;
        width: 300px;
        float: left;
        height: 2000px;
    }

    #master {
        padding: 10px;
        margin-left: 300px;
    }

    #group {

    }

    #topper {
        height: 30px;
        background-color: green;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        width: inherit;
    }

    .containers {
        background-color: blue;
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        margin-right: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        float: left;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="app">
    <div id="sideBar"></div>
    <div id="master">
        <div id="group">
            <div id="topper"></div>
            <div class="containers"></div>
            <div class="containers"></div>
            <div class="containers"></div>
            <div class="containers"></div>
            <div class="containers"></div>
            <div class="containers"></div>
            <div class="containers"></div>
            <div class="containers"></div>
            <div class="containers"></div>
            <div class="containers"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Another scenario of resizing: The important is: Containers is always fixed width, displays as many possible in a single row and the most important: the green div always get aligned with the containers bellow.

[image: second scenario]

Comment: Almost there :( but the containers cannot change the width/height...must be fixed. When I resize the window, the containers must wrap to the row bellow. Example: if I'm in a 4K LCD, in a single row I can have about 7 containers in a single row. In a 1024 lcd, 2, in a 1440 lcd, maybe 3...in other words: containers must be fixed width in pixels.

Answer (score 0):

If I get it correctly, this is what you're after (assuming that you can set the width and height of the blue boxes via `calc`).

`flexbox` and `calc` come in handy over here, as they can do the hard work. I've set the `max-width` on the `.right-container` to 75% just to show what it's doing.

You can set the `width` of the blue boxes to 50%, but then you need to change the `padding-bottom` to 50% as well.

```css
body {
  background: black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.left-container {
  background: red;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
}

.right-container {
  margin-left: 120px;
  max-width: 70%;
  width: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}

.top-box {
  width: 100%;
  background: lime;
  height: 50px;
}

.list-boxes {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 10px -10px;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: stretch;
}

.box-item {
  background: blue;
  flex-basis: calc(100% /3);
  padding-bottom: calc(100%/3);
  border: 10px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="left-container">

  </div>

  <div class="right-container">

    <div class="top-box">

    </div>

    <ul class="list-boxes">
      <li class="box-item">
        <div class="box">

        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="box-item">
        <div class="box">

        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="box-item">
        <div class="box">

        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="box-item">
        <div class="box">

        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="box-item">
        <div class="box">

        </div>
      </li>

    </ul>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I updated my question to expose a better scenario. The container must be fixed width/height. The green div width must "follow" according with the containers presents in a single row.

Comment: No, Roy..in your example, the containers is being resized proportionally. It's must obey the 300px x 300px.  When the window resize, the containers must wraps to the row bellow. It could be my fault to not be capable to explain better :( sorry for this. Trying to do my best. 
Check pic1 and pic2 - pic1 had 2 containers in a row, like a window with 1024px. pic2 had 3 containers in a window of more or less 1400px. in a 4k window, I could have about 7 containers in a single row. Always 300x300